# Customer wise tax in Magento 2

Tags: customer, tax, magento-2.1.7

I have to apply custom tax by customer wise.

For example from Admin attribute is given to apply customer  wise tax or not.

If this option is enabled than apply additional 10% tax to customer.

I have added attribute to the customer in Admin side, but not getting solution to add customer wise tax.

Please give me some suggestion or help.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are asking for is already implemented in magento 2 in form of tax classes which you can assign to customer groups.
Follow this [link](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-class-configure.html) to know how to configure it.

Comment: No i have to do this on attribute base.

Comment: You can easily assign customer group to each customer, there would be no need for attributes or any additional coding

Comment: My requirement is that it will be apply as additional tax so one regular tax and other customer base tax both will be apply like additional fee. i need to apply only based on attribute selection of customer.